# Django: Remove / of slug

Tags: python, django

The issue I am dealing with is the form error "Enter a valid 'slug' consisting of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens."

The following is my form field validation:

```
def clean_slug(self):
        slug = self.cleaned_data['slug']
        if slug.endswith('/'):
            self.cleaned_data['slug'] = slug[:-1]
        slug_check = self.organizer.events.filter(slug=slug).exclude(pk=self.event.pk).exists()
        if slug_check:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Slug already exists"), code='duplicated_slug')
        return slug
```

Somehow Django is not considering my `self.cleaned_data['slug'] = slug[:-1]`when `is_valid()` is being called. Do you know why?

Comment: Guess: it's because you continue using the old value of slug, not the updated one without the /. Does it work if you do `slug = slug[:-1]` instead?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Same issue. It seems like Django is doing some validation before already.

Comment: Is possible that the ending `/` is not the only `/` in `slug`? It smell like it where an url address ;) try `self.cleaned_data['slug'] = slug.replace('/', '')`

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying `cleaned_data['slug']` which will have no effect. Django will used what you return from this method, and you are returning the original (unmodified) `slug`. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation):

> The return value of this method replaces the existing value in cleaned_data, so it must be the field’s value from cleaned_data (even if this method didn’t change it) or a new cleaned value.

Change it to:

```
def clean_slug(self):
    slug = self.cleaned_data['slug']
    if slug.endswith('/'):
        slug = slug[:-1]  # <-- Modify slug, not cleaned_data['slug']
    slug_check = self.organizer.events.filter(slug=slug).exclude(pk=self.event.pk).exists()
    if slug_check:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Slug already exists"), code='duplicated_slug')
    return slug  # <-- return modified value
```